# R loop missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, loops, na

I've got this code in R:

```
j <- 1
k <- nrow(group_IDs)

  while (j <= k)
        {   
            d_clust <- Mclust(Customers_Attibutes_s[which    (Customers_Attibutes_s$Group_ID == group_IDs$Group_ID[j]),3:7], G=2:7)
            temp <- cbind(Customers_Attibutes[which        (Customers_Attibutes$Group_ID == group_IDs$Group_ID[j]),], as.data.frame    (predict.Mclust(d_clust, Customers_Attibutes[which(Customers_Attibutes$Group_ID     == group_IDs$Group_ID[j]), 3:7]))[1])
            temp_ <- rbind(temp,temp_)
            j <- j+1
        }
```

`j <= k` in the while statement is returning this error:

> missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed.

`group_IDs` is not null and it actually contains the value 8 in this case.
It seems to get into the loop and crash at the second round.

Comment: Can you show us what group_IDs looks like?

Comment: What does `nrow(group_IDs)` return?

Comment: nrow(group_IDs)  is a vector that in this case contains just one value. The value is number 8 but it could be any series of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get around the indexing issues using `for`, e.g.:

`for (ID in group_IDs) {}`

This, of course, assumes that group_IDs is a vector of values.

Note: Your code shows the following inside the loop `group_IDs$Group_ID[j]` which implies something other than a vector; perhaps you meant `group_IDs[j]`?

Comment: Technically it's a dataframe with one column. I've tried that too.

Comment: In that case: `for (ID in group_IDs$Group_ID)`

Answer (score 0):

Since `group_ IDs`is a vector, try `length(group_IDs)` instead of `nrow`. A vector doesn't have rows, so the equivalent is `length`.

Here's what I suspect is happening:

```
> group_IDs <- 8
> nrow(group_IDs)
NULL
```

Comment: I didn't know nrow could return a vector? The OP specified in the original question that "group_IDs... contains the value 8", so I assume that is the vector of which they speak?

Comment: Either Length or nrow it keeps throwing the same error.

Comment: Technically it's a dataframe with one column

Comment: Group_IDs is generated by this: group_IDs <- sqldf("select distinct Group_ID from txns")

Comment: So `nrow(group_IDs)` returns `1` then?

Comment: After running the code without the loop, what do `k` and `j` return? Does simply running `k<=j` return a logical value, or the same error as you're seeing?

Comment: When I run the code without the loop j is just 1 and I'm not using k.

Comment: What I mean is, run lines 1:2, then lines 6:9. Then evaluate `k` and `j`, and try running `k<=j`; that's essentially what your loop is doing the second time around, so it may give some insight into your issue.